# joining tables with specialization-generalization relationship in oracle

Tags: oracle, join

I am trying to do a join with two tables.  One is a supertype and one is a subtype.  I am also trying to join it with another table and that works but the joining of the supertype and subtype is not.  It says I have invalid identifier but he same id is in both so I am extremely confused why it's not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDYu1.png)

I included my code below and the attachment shows my tables.  I have a table I am pulling first name and last name from and my other code is pulling from the supertype and subtype table.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, gift_card_id, value_of_card
FROM gift_card 
JOIN subject ON gift_card.subject_id = subject.subject_id
JOIN gift_card ON visa_gift_card.gift_card_id = gift_card.gift_card_id
GROUP BY gift_card.gift_Card_id
HAVING visa_gift_card.gift_card_id = gift_card.gift_card_id;
```

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you don't have `first_name` or `last_name` in any of your tables. Is there another table you should be joining on?

Also, I don't think `group by`/`having` is what you want, since you have no aggregate functions like `sum` in your select list.